# Xamarin UWP : Picker displays class name when string.empty is selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I  have following code in Xamarin forms project.

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Picker x:Name="picker"
                Title="Select a monkey"
                TitleColor="Red">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String> </x:String>
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
```

if you notice the 1st choice in picker is the empty string. when I run on Android I get proper value displayed. but when I run on windows platform and select the 1st option and the class name is displayed in the picker field.

the field displays: `Xamarin.Forms.Picker`

[image]

[image]

I would like to have this displayed as empty string than a class name.

Comment: I recommend using an ObservableCollection in your code behind or ViewMolde (if using MVVM) to use as source for the List, then programmatically setting the first element as selected when the page is open, like this: `picker.SelectedItem = list.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: hey @MateusW.  , my issue is not with the selection from the list data. the above code is just an example to show my problem. The issue is with the display of the empty data being displayed in windows platform. it gives the class name instead of showing the empty string.

Comment: I've never debugged on UWP but this is a strange behavior to me. If you use 1 space instead of an empty string (" ") it still shows the class?

Comment: @MateusW. yes, it's the same behavior for any number of whitespace. and even for empty string too.

Comment: Odd. There's not much documentation or bug reports on UWP unfortunately. I guess you would have to override something form the native Picker class. Try creating a class that extends Picker and make sure to display nothing when an empty string is selected. If that doesn't work, I'd start looking for alternatives (maybe an auto-complete input).

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** In native UWP platform , we need to set `xml:space="preserve"` in xaml to keep space of string . However,we don't support (yet) `xml:space` in Xamarin. So when you set the value as empty ,it will been identified as `null`.

**Solution:** You can set the ItemsSource of picker in code behind as a workaround .